# Real time line chart for android?

Tags: android, graph, charts, jfreechart, achartengine

Can anyone recommend a library open-source for android that supports real-time rendering? I need to make a ECG line chart.

I Googled and all I found are library with fee like [graphwidget](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=11&ved=0CBoQFjAAOAo&url=http://graphwidget.android-libraries.com/content/overview&rct=j&q=real%20time%20library%20android&ei=yJcxTuHUPMnKsQLkiK3oCw&usg=AFQjCNHK5apCB64YVO-bFA0KKxgCiPqlHw&sig2=OxXDVRM4n4pIE_VGulNPeg&cad=rja) or [aichart](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=14&ved=0CDYQFjADOAo&url=http://www.artfulbits.com/products/android/aicharts.aspx&rct=j&q=real%20time%20library%20android&ei=yJcxTuHUPMnKsQLkiK3oCw&usg=AFQjCNFZ-LxRXX6D4Ajfp8qKROg7nJm3lg&sig2=_izA2rDWNuWZJEaJqB1odA&cad=rja)..

Comment: Any solution to this issue?  I've looked at Tricorder too but the library is too huge to use in my app as I have to plot realtime data at about 256 samples per sec.

Answer (score 1):

There's [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/index.html) and [GraphView](http://android.arnodenhond.com/components/graphview). You may also want to search for Java charting and not specifically Android charting.

Comment: does it support real time data?

Comment: Graphview is just a basic program that takes in a fixed array.  No real time graphing there but you can update the graph's array and redraw.